# Facebook Open Graph Protocol on Tumblr

Tags: facebook, tumblr, facebook-opengraph

When a link from my Tumblr blog is posted on Facebook, Facebook grabs the title between the title tags and not the one specified in the Open Graph meta tags. Why is it doing this? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you post a sample link? Already tried the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)? What did it tell you?

Answer (score 17):

Without seeing the code, I'm not sure what you're problem is exactly, but for anyone else searching for this looking for how to set up Open Graph on their blog, try doing something like this:

```
<!-- FACEBOOK OPEN GRAPH -->
<!-- >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-->

<meta property="og:site_name" content="{Title}"/>

{block:PermalinkPage}

    <meta property="og:url" content="{Permalink}"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>

        {block:Posts}
            {block:Text}
                {block:Title}<meta property="og:title" content="{PlaintextTitle}"/>{/block:Title}
                <meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextBody}"/>
            {/block:Text}

            {block:Photo}
                <meta property="og:image" content="{PhotoURL-500}"/>
                {block:Caption}<meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextCaption}"/>{/block:Caption}
            {/block:Photo}

            {block:Photoset}
                {block:Photos}
                <meta property="og:image" content="{PhotoURL-500}"/>
                {/block:Photos}
                {block:Caption}<meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextCaption}"/>{/block:Caption}
            {/block:Photoset}

            {block:Quote}
                <meta property="og:title" content="{PlaintextQuote}"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextSource}"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-64}"/>
            {/block:Quote}

            {block:Link}
                <meta property="og:title" content="{PlaintextName}"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextDescription}"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-64}"/>
            {/block:Link}

            {block:Chat}
                <meta property="og:title" content="{PlaintextTitle}"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="{block:Lines}{block:Label}{Label}: {/block:Label}{Line} &bull; {/block:Lines}"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-64}"/>
            {/block:Chat}

            {block:Audio}
                <meta property="og:title" content="{block:Artist}{Artist} - {/block:Artist}{block:TrackName}{TrackName}{/block:TrackName}"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextCaption}"/>
                {block:AlbumArt}<meta property="og:image" content="{AlbumArtURL}"/>{/block:AlbumArt}
            {/block:Audio}

            {block:Video}
                {block:Caption}<meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextCaption}"/>{/block:Caption}
            {/block:Video}

            {block:Answer}
                <meta property="og:title" content="{PlaintextQuestion}"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextAnswer}"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-64}"/>
            {/block:Answer}

        {/block:Posts}

{/block:PermalinkPage}

{block:IndexPage}
        <meta property="og:title" content="{Title}"/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="blog"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="{MetaDescription}"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="{PortraitURL-64}"/>
{/block:IndexPage}
```

Should cover just about anything you can through at it!

Remember that all of the code belongs before the closing `</head>` tag.

Comment: Why is there a downvote for providing lots of useful information that could help the user solve their problem?

Comment: I noticed Tumblr adds their own Facebook & Twitter metadata. This may come in handy to mix the above answer with what Tumblr generates (this is from my blog, swap the values with data from your tumblr site):

https://gist.github.com/chuckbergeron/5106e3e72c8e7e8d54d2c189f472e5d3