# TUMBLR og:image should be larger [edited: more code]

Tags: css, facebook, object, facebook-opengraph, tumblr

I've added *two* widgets to my blog - http://www.raisethecurve.com - one on the sidebar and one attached to each post.

I've uploaded a 900x900 og:image to the tumblr static servers, which can be found in my

[FB Debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.raisethecurve.com/)

After scouring the forum and applying every fix I could find, nothing has worked.

**What stumps me the most about this is the fact that the sidebar box_count widget works, but the post-embed widget doesn't.**

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be grateful for your help.

```
<!-- FACEBOOK OPEN GRAPH -->
<!-- >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-->

<meta property="og:site_name" content="{Title}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Poetry, Prose, and Who Knows." />

{block:PermalinkPage}
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{Permalink}" />

        {block:Posts}
            {block:Text}
                {block:Title} 
                <meta property="og:title" content="{PlaintextTitle}"/>{/block:Title}
                <meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextBody}"/>
            {/block:Text}

            {block:Photo}
                <meta property="og:image" content="{PhotoURL-500}"/>
                {block:Caption}<meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextCaption}"/>{/block:Caption}
            {/block:Photo}

            {block:Photoset}
                {block:Photos}
                <meta property="og:image" content="{PhotoURL-500}"/>
                {/block:Photos}
                {block:Caption}<meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextCaption}"/>{/block:Caption}
            {/block:Photoset}

            {block:Quote}
                <meta property="og:title" content="{PlaintextQuote}"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextSource}"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content="http://static.tumblr.com/k81rzib/vCnmygjui/finalogo.jpg" />
            {/block:Quote}

            {block:Link}
                <meta property="og:title" content="{PlaintextName}"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextDescription}"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content="http://static.tumblr.com/k81rzib/vCnmygjui/finalogo.jpg" />
            {/block:Link}

            {block:Chat}
                <meta property="og:title" content="{PlaintextTitle}"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="{block:Lines}{block:Label}{Label}: {/block:Label}{Line} &bull; {/block:Lines}"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content="http://static.tumblr.com/k81rzib/vCnmygjui/finalogo.jpg" />
            {/block:Chat}

            {block:Audio}
                <meta property="og:title" content="{block:Artist}{Artist} - {/block:Artist}{block:TrackName}{TrackName}{/block:TrackName}"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextCaption}"/>
                {block:AlbumArt}<meta property="og:image" content="{AlbumArtURL}"/>{/block:AlbumArt}
            {/block:Audio}

            {block:Video}
                {block:Caption}<meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextCaption}"/>{/block:Caption}
            {/block:Video}

            {block:Answer}
                <meta property="og:title" content="{PlaintextQuestion}"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextAnswer}"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content="http://static.tumblr.com/k81rzib/vCnmygjui/finalogo.jpg" />
            {/block:Answer}
        {/block:Posts}
{/block:PermalinkPage}

{block:IndexPage}
<meta property="og:type" content="blog" />
<meta property="og:title" content="{Title}" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{BlogURL}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static.tumblr.com/k81rzib/vCnmygjui/finalogo.jpg" />
{/block:IndexPage}
```

---

```
                                                            {block:Date}
                                                        <div class="meta">
                                                            <ul class="meta-list">
                                                                {block:HasTags}
                                                                <li class="tags">
                                                                    <ul class="tag-list">
                                                                        {block:Tags}
                                                                        <li><a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a></li>
                                                                        {/block:Tags}
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                </li>
                                                                {/block:HasTags}
                                                                {block:IfShowGroupBlogInfo}<li class="post-author"><img alt="{PostAuthorName} Avatar" src="{PostAuthorPortraitURL-16}"> Posted by <a href="{PostAuthorURL}">{PostAuthorName}</a></li>{/block:IfShowGroupBlogInfo}
                                                                <li class="date{block:RebloggedFrom}-reblogged{/block:RebloggedFrom}"><a href="{Permalink}" title="{ShortDayOfWeek}. {Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year} @ {12Hour}:{Minutes} {AmPm}"><span class="icon"></span>{TimeAgo}</a>{block:RebloggedFrom} <em>&gt;</em> <a class="reblogged-from" href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootTitle}">{ReblogRootName}</a>{/block:RebloggedFrom}</li>
                                                                {block:NoteCount}<li class="notes"><a href="{Permalink}#notes"><span class="icon"></span>{NoteCount}</a></li>{/block:NoteCount}
                                                                {block:IfDisqusShortname}<li class="comments hidden"><a id="dsq-{PostID}" href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread"><span class="icon"></span>Comments</a></li>{/block:IfDisqusShortname}
                                                                <li class="permalink"><a href="{Permalink}"><span class="icon"></span>{lang:Permalink}</a></li>
                                                            </ul><!--/.meta-list -->                                                                
              </div>                   
                                <!-- /.meta -->
<!-- Custom code for index page social buttons -->                 
<!-- Custom code for like and reblog button -->
<ul class="like_and_reblog_buttons">
<li>{LikeButton color="grey"}</li>
<li>{ReblogButton color="black"}</li>
<!-- End custom code for like and reblog buttons -->
<!-- Custom code for google plus widget -->
   <li><div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" data-annotation="none" data-href="{ShortURL}"></div></li>
<!-- End custom code for google plus widget -->
<!-- Custom code for Twitter widget -->
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="{Title}" data-via="RaiseTheCurve" data-hashtags="Tumblr" data-url="{ShortURL}" data-counturl="{Permalink}" data-count="horizontal" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>
        <script async"true">!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script></li>
<!-- End custom code for Twitter widget -->
<!-- Custom code for facebook widget -->
<li><div class="fb-like" data-href="{ShortURL}" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div></li>
<!-- End custom code for facebook widget -->
</ul>
<!--End custom code for index page social buttons -->
{/block:Date}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, your theme is requesting an image that is 500px or less:

```
{block:Photo}
    <meta property="og:image" content="{PhotoURL-500}"/>
    {block:Caption}<meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextCaption}"/>{/block:Caption}
{/block:Photo}
```

To request the largest image, you will need to use the following theme block / variable:

```
{block:Photo}
    <meta property="og:image" content="{block:HighRes}{PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:HighRes}"/>
    {block:Caption}<meta property="og:description" content="{PlaintextCaption}"/>{/block:Caption}
{/block:Photo}
```

I would advise caution here, if there isn't a high resolution version of the image available a fallback URL isn't always provided.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your input! I do not have high res images as I post 500x700px images to adapt to the flow of the Tumblr dashboard (500px wide). I tried replacing the {PhotoURL} in Photo and Photoset with my logo to no avail. Same error, same behavior. Ironically, the photo posts on my blog are the only ones that work correctly from the embedded like/share widget -- albeit the image is cropped on the y axis.

Comment: Hi, my pleasure. Based on your comment, I need some clarification? Sharing posts from the IndexPage isn't something Tumblr really supports. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, I essentially tacked onto [THIS CODE](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#like_and_reblog_buttons) by adding more <li> elements to the body. It works wonderfully for Twitter and Google Plus, and Facebook too, honestly, save for the og:image issue. I'll add my admittedly hacked up code to the original question for your perusal.

Comment: Hmm, so to clarify, you want to share something from the indexpage? I think this covers what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11588197/2312574

Comment: I am of the belief that the problem is fixed. FB Debug is no longer showing an error and the further I go back through my pages, the more I see the correct logo. I'm guessing this was a caching issue more than anything (namely because I'm still seeing a deprecated logo version with no reference in the current code) and I hope time will iron out the wrinkles. Thanks for all your help, @mike !